# In mySQL, how can I select the most recent time_stamp for each client_id across multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have various tables in my database, each table corresponds to a specific type of message. Various clients save messages to the database at regular intervals, but depending on what's happening they might save a message or messages to one or more tables.  There are 4 tables.
Each table has a format as follows:

```
client_id | time_stamp | var1 | var2 | var3 | ...
```

where `client_id` is a `VARCHAR` field and `time_stamp` is an SQL `TIMESTAMP` in the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`. The `var`'s are different for each table.

There is also a clients table with details about the client like this:

```
id | name | type | etc....
```

the `client_id` on the message tables corresponds to the `id` on the client table. the `id` is also the primary key of the client table.

I want to query the database to find the latest time_stamp for each client, across all the tables. So in my results I should get a list of `client_id`'s and the `time_stamp` for the last time they contacted the server, like this:

```
id | time_stamp
1  |  12/2/15...
2  |  11/2/15...
...etc
```

I thought I could do this with a join, but now I understand that that is not the case. My join statement gave me a `client_id` and a column for each `time_stamp` from each table; also, as a result, it only returned a row for clients that had saved at least one message to all tables.
So I'm obviously way off the mark here. 
can anyone help me out?

My incorrect SQL statement is as follows:

```
SELECT clients.id
     , msg_type_1.time_stamp
     , msg_type_2.time_stamp
     , msg_type_3.time_stamp
     , msg_type_4.time_stamp 
  FROM devices 
  JOIN msg_type_1 
    ON msg_type_1.client_id = clients.id 
  JOIN msg_type_2 
    ON msg_type_2.client_id = clients.id 
  JOIN msg_type_3 
    ON msg_type_3.client_id = clients.id 
  JOIN msg_type_4 
    ON msg_type_4.client_id = clients.id 
 GROUP 
    BY id
```

Comment: where's your clients table?

Comment: What is a timestamp?

Comment: @Strawberry An SQL TIMESTAMP in the format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss, but I believe it might be stored as a long

Comment: Can you amend your question accordingly. It's confusing as currently written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select client_id, max(time_stamp)
from 
  (select client_id, max(time_stamp) as time_stamp
  from table 1
  group by client_id
  union
  select client_id, max(time_stamp) as time_stamp
  from table 2
  group by client_id
  union
  select client_id, max(time_stamp) as time_stamp
  from table 3
  group by client_id
  union
  select client_id, max(time_stamp) as time_stamp
  from table 4
 group by client_id)
group by client_id
```

Comment: Well, at the beginning, what are you selecting max(time_stamp) from?

Comment: Good catch. I'm hoping (but haven't tested) that by using MAX in the subquery, the overall query will be faster. I guess the query optimizer would do that anyway...

Comment: Only the first "as time_stamp" is required in the union - the column names of the union result are those from the first select. Column names from subsequent selected are ignored. But this is a good answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! this is exactly what I was looking for. I had to add another `as result_table` after the closing bracket at  the end, but once i did that it worked perfectly!

Comment: What exactly is `group by` doing here?